# Javascript library to create heroku dashboard like app

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please point me to any standard library/ tool that can be used to build a [heroku status type dashboard](https://status.heroku.com/) quickly ?

Comment: What you meant by type? You need a timeline like in Heroku Status Dashboard?

Comment: Yes, a timeline dashboard. the difference here is that there are 2 axis, one for Production and one for DEV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions

[timeline.knightlab.com](http://timeline.knightlab.com/) is a good fit, you can link a Google Spreadsheet to it and when you add data to the spreadsheet, it will render these data as a timeline on your webpage.

[tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/02/vertical-timeline](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/02/vertical-timeline/) you can follow this tutorial also, it guides you how to create one, and they have a demo and source code of the demo.

[tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery/)
is same as above.

Try [http://timeglider.com/widget](http://timeglider.com/widget/index.php) also.

UPDATE

if you want a timeline with 2 axes, you can follow the Tympanus vertical timeline tutorial. Simply creating 2 timelines stacked side by side would do.

Also, you can use two sides of the axis to separate the Dev and Production like in  'lateral on scroll sliding with jquery' example.

If you follow the above tutorials, you can hack the codes to fix it for your need.

Comment: is there a way for adding 2 event streams to a timeline. For ex add production and dev timelines like in the heroku dashboard